# How do I force cognitive services to return an error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to test out my error handling code when calling into Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services. I'm trying to make sure I handle any potential return error codes. Is there a way to simulate or force Cognitive services to return a specific error? Or am I going to have to mock cognitive services and send my error codes to my tests?

Comment: I would say it depends on which error code you want to try... but if you want to be exhaustive on the possibilities, you will have to mock them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as I known, there are only two kind of HTTP response status codes in MS Azure Cognitive Services: `20x` (such as 200, 202) represent to success calling, and not `20x` like 400, 415, 500 represent to failed calling with error.

So I think you just need to handle two potential return status codes: `20x` and not `20x`. Error is error, not for all error codes to make the related handle code, just record it with logging.

Of couse, there be the API references of all cognitive service https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/, you can collect the error codes of response status code for all APIs of all services by yourself to build a mock service to test your code.